# How to generate client certificate in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

Whenever I tried to create self-signed certificate, it always generate Server Certificate and I'm not able to find the way to create Client certificate which I want to use in my client application while it communicate with server(WCF application).

Comment: http://www.yangsoft.com/blog/?p=105 see this article

Comment: Unable to find the proper steps, how to create client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

first you need a root CA. Then you can create the certificates. Here is a good tutorial from MS. Take a look at Step 7:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx

I hope this helps you